# Imprimir datos con iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp, imprimir

**Buenas, supongamos que tengo un certificado como este (obviamente bien colorido, con mil detalles, impreso en una hoja especial):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creditos correspondientes a su autor [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=chamilo&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&tbs=simg:CAESoQIJi_1rKMXhkUgcalQILELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKKITqBOJCKYTgQihE6sTqROKE8kdyT3_1Pco9gD7-Pcc92T39Pcg9lT0aMOk9RTdKiCvDQRK2kCtWe5npIOIh1BUeBKSlFtBTqb_12M6TzUJzQzm8sy8_1eiBFDUSAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEtbMIjAwLEJ3twQkajQEKHQoKc2NyZWVuc2hvdNqliPYDCwoJL20vMDF6Ym53ChsKCGRvY3VtZW502qWI9gMLCgkvbS8wMTVidjMKGAoGY2lyY2xl2qWI9gMKCggvbS8wMXZrbAoYCgZvcmFuZ2XapYj2AwoKCC9tLzBqY19wChsKCHBhcmFsbGVs2qWI9gMLCgkvbS8wMzB6Zm4M&fir=ymIgiOXudIF6hM%252C0NIGDVo7m4EWZM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQ8tSsWH_JE8s6j1TFxZ9-9Hj9bAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXiZbVjtXsAhUtD7kGHY0SBqMQ9QF6BAgLEAQ&biw=1280&bih=609#imgrc=ymIgiOXudIF6hM)

Lo que busco, es poner ese **certificado** en la impresora y mediante mi aplicación de **C#**, setear datos mediante una consulta a `SQL Server` que realizo obteniendo el valor numérico de una celda en un `DataGridView`

Este es mi código para llenar con datos el **pdf**, **actualizado en base a la respuesta que medieron**:

```
private void datos48(bool enviarAImpresora = false, string nombreImpresora = "")
{
    Certificados certificados = new Certificados();

    const int nroColumna = 1;
    certificados.DniNumero = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow columna in dtgSuscriptor.Rows)
    {
        certificados.DniNumero = Convert.ToDouble(columna.Cells[nroColumna].Value);
    }
    PdfReader oReader = new PdfReader(pathPDF);
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle oSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1500, 1800);
    Document oDocument = new Document(oSize);

    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();            
    pathPDFCompleto = enviarAImpresora ? $"archivoTemporal{guid}.pdf" : pathPDFCompleto;
    FileStream oFS = new FileStream(pathPDFCompleto, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    PdfWriter oWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oDocument, oFS);
    oDocument.Open();

    PdfContentByte oPDF = oWriter.DirectContent;

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    oPDF.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    oPDF.SetFontAndSize(bf, 22);

    oPDF.BeginText();

    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(210, oSize.Height - 213);
    oPDF.ShowText("Franco Ejemplo");

    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(160, oSize.Height - 243);
    oPDF.ShowText("Domicilio ejempolo");

    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(410, oSize.Height - 243);
    oPDF.ShowText("localidad");

    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(160, oSize.Height - 265);
    oPDF.ShowText("provincia");

    oPDF.EndText();
    PdfImportedPage page = oWriter.GetImportedPage(oReader, 1);
    oDocument.NewPage();

    oDocument.Close();
    oFS.Close();
    oWriter.Close();
    oReader.Close();

    if (enviarAImpresora)
    {
        Imprimir(pathPDFCompleto, nombreImpresora);
    }
}

private void Imprimir(string archivoTemporal, string nombreImpresora)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo gsProcessInfo;
        Process gsProcess;
        gsProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        gsProcessInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
        gsProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        gsProcessInfo.FileName = archivoTemporal;
        gsProcessInfo.Arguments = "\"" + nombreImpresora + "\"";
        gsProcess = Process.Start(gsProcessInfo);
        if (gsProcess.HasExited == false)
        {
            gsProcess.Kill();
        }
        gsProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        gsProcess.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(archivoTemporal);
    }
}
```

EL código, no me ha funcionado puesto que no manda a imprimir nada. Se lo asigno al **botón** en el caso `true`:

```
    private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datos48(true, "Brother MFC-8460N USB Printer");
    }
```

No sucede nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el caso de asignar false:

```
    private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datos48(false, "Brother MFC-8460N USB Printer");
    }
```

No sucede nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe como puedo lograr lo que digo? Sino me di a entender, me avisan

Comment: Pregunta, dices que ya tienes un tipo formulario listo para ser impreso verdad? y quieres solo imprimir los valores, esto seria un tipo template, entonces lo que quieres es que el sistema automáticamente mande el PDF generado a la impresora en lugar de enviarlo a un documento?

Comment: Claro, lo que yo tengo es un papel físico con el diseño del documento (es como un formulario que llenas manualmente). En el código, yo cargo un PDF con el formulario que ya está impreso (lo hice para posicionar los valores), pero no tengo que cargar el PDF porque el diseño ya está. Es como dices, necesito es que el sistema mande a la impresora los valores y esta los imprima. @CristinaCarrasco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías utilizar algo como esto:

```
private void datos48(bool enviarAImpresora = false, string nombreImpresora = "")
{
    Certificados certificados = new Certificados();

    const int nroColumna = 1;
    certificados.DniNumero = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow columna in dtgSuscriptor.Rows)
    {
        certificados.DniNumero = Convert.ToDouble(columna.Cells[nroColumna].Value);
    }

    //Objeto para leer el pdf original
    PdfReader oReader = new PdfReader(pathPDF);
    //Objeto que tiene el tamaño de nuestro documento
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle oSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1500, 1800); //oReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    //Documento de itexsharp para realizar el trabajo asignandole el tamaño original
    Document oDocument = new Document(oSize);

    //Creamos el objeto en el cual haremos la inserción
    string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();            
    pathPDFCompleto = enviarAImpresora ? $"archivoTemporal{guid}.pdf" : pathPDFCompleto;
    FileStream oFS = new FileStream(pathPDFCompleto, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    PdfWriter oWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oDocument, oFS);
    oDocument.Open();

    //El contenido del pdf, aquí se hace la escritura del contenido
    PdfContentByte oPDF = oWriter.DirectContent;

    //Propiedades de nuestra fuente a insertar
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    oPDF.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    oPDF.SetFontAndSize(bf, 22);

    //Se abre el flujo para escribir el texto
    oPDF.BeginText();
    //Le damos posición y rotación al texto
    //La posición de Y es al revés de como estamos acostumbrados

    //mitad arriba - nombre
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(210, oSize.Height - 213);
    oPDF.ShowText("Franco Ejemplo");

    //mitad arriba - domicilio
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(160, oSize.Height - 243);
    oPDF.ShowText("Domicilio ejempolo");

    //mitad arriba - localidad
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(410, oSize.Height - 243);
    oPDF.ShowText("localidad");

    //mitad arriba - provincia
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(160, oSize.Height - 265);
    oPDF.ShowText("provincia");

    //mitad arriba - dni
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(435, oSize.Height - 270);
    oPDF.ShowText("dni");

    //mitad arriba - solicitud
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(173, oSize.Height - 298);
    oPDF.ShowText("Solicitud");

    //mitad arriba - emision
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(440, oSize.Height - 299);
    oPDF.ShowText("emision");

    //mitad arriba - plan
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(127, oSize.Height - 324);
    oPDF.ShowText("plan");

    //mitad arriba - cuota
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(434, oSize.Height - 329);
    oPDF.ShowText("Cuota");

    //mitad arriba - descrip
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(172, oSize.Height - 353);
    oPDF.ShowText("Desripcion");

    //mitad arriba - valnom
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(432, oSize.Height - 359);
    oPDF.ShowText("Val nom");

    /////////////////mitad abajo

    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(40, oSize.Height - 546);
    oPDF.ShowText("Franco ejempolo");

    //mitad abajo - dni
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(40, oSize.Height - 575);
    oPDF.ShowText("dni");

    //mitad abajo - domicilio
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(40, oSize.Height - 602);
    oPDF.ShowText("Domicilio ejemplo");

    //mitad abajo - Barrio
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(40, oSize.Height - 630);
    oPDF.ShowText("barrio");

    //mitad abajo - localidad
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(172, oSize.Height - 630);
    oPDF.ShowText("localidad");

    //mitad abajo - provincia
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(40, oSize.Height - 656);
    oPDF.ShowText("provincia");

    //mitad abajo - teléfono
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(172, oSize.Height - 656);
    oPDF.ShowText("telefono");

    //mitad abajo - asesor
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(40, oSize.Height - 803);
    oPDF.ShowText("asesor");

    //mitad abajo - solicitud
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(306, oSize.Height - 545);
    oPDF.ShowText("Solicitud");

    //mitad abajo - plan
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(452, oSize.Height - 545);
    oPDF.ShowText("Plan");

    //mitad abajo - descrip
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(306, oSize.Height - 575);
    oPDF.ShowText("Desripcion");

    //mitad abajo - valnom
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(306, oSize.Height - 602);
    oPDF.ShowText("Val nom");

    //mitad abajo - cuota
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(452, oSize.Height - 602);
    oPDF.ShowText("Cuota");

    //mitad abajo - cobrador
    oPDF.SetTextMatrix(306, oSize.Height - 803);
    oPDF.ShowText("Cobrador");

    oPDF.EndText();
    PdfImportedPage page = oWriter.GetImportedPage(oReader, 1);
    //oPDF.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    oDocument.NewPage();

    //Cerramos los objetos utilizados
    oDocument.Close();
    oFS.Close();
    oWriter.Close();
    oReader.Close();

    if (enviarAImpresora)
    {
        //Imprimir(pathPDFCompleto, nombreImpresora);
        ImprimirPDF(pathPDFCompleto, nombreImpresora);
    }
}
/*
private void Imprimir(string archivoTemporal, string nombreImpresora)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo gsProcessInfo;
        Process gsProcess;
        gsProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        gsProcessInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
        gsProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        gsProcessInfo.FileName = archivoTemporal;
        gsProcessInfo.Arguments = "\"" + nombreImpresora + "\"";
        gsProcess = Process.Start(gsProcessInfo);
        if (gsProcess.HasExited == false)
        {
            gsProcess.Kill();
        }
        gsProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        gsProcess.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(archivoTemporal);
    }

}*/
```

Actualización:

1. Instala el siguiente Nuget

[**RawPrint**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RawPrint/)

> pm>  Install-Package RawPrint -Version 0.5.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Utiliza este método para la impresión (recuerda agregar `using RawPrint;`):

   ```
   public void ImprimirPDF(string nombreArchivo, string nombreImpresora )
   {
       // Crea la instancia de la impresora
       IPrinter printer = new Printer();
       // Imprime el archivo
       printer.PrintRawFile(nombreImpresora, nombreArchivo);
   }
   ```

Comment: Antes que nada, gracias por tu respuesta. He actualizado la pregunta, conforme a tu código. Espero puedas revisarlo :)

Comment: Podrías intentar corriendo tu programa como administrador?, déjame ver creo que hay una función también para lanzar un Process como admin.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda